# Find nearest date in excel index/match from two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to get the nearest date from one column based on a date and id from another column. For example:

```
01-001  1/5/2017
01-002  12/28/2016
01-003  1/5/2017
01-001  8/21/2017
```

The second set of data would be:

```
01-002  11/4/2016
01-002  6/24/2016
01-002  12/25/2016
01-003  1/14/2017
```

For 01-002, I'd want to return 12/25/2016 from the second set of data. There has to be some sort of array index match with Max to do this, I just can't put it all together.

Comment: If you  are using excel 2016 it has a MAXIF/MINIF function that would be they key for you

Comment: I think that works, here's how to use it if anyone wants to know https://exceljet.net/formula/max-if-criteria-match

Comment: well that's the old way @mcadamsjustin if you have the new version of excel it integrates both functions in one.

Comment: I'm not sure what this new formula is, but I don't think it matches my ID's (01-002)

Comment: @mcadamsjustin, AGGREGATE has been the better pseudo-MAXIFS/MINIFS replacement since xl2010. If you can accept that xl2007 was a transitional (i.e. test) version, then xl2010 is the *de facto* standard for posting solutions.

Answer (score 2):

These work! See photos below. Unfortunately cannot see ranges highlighted without entering formula bar...which removes the array formula brackets { }

You likely forgot to set the equation using the array formula. You can do this by hitting CTRL SHIFT ENTER rather than enter. It would not have mattered though as the formula was broken! Sometimes tinkering gets you into trouble!

New equation.

```
{=INDEX(C7:C10,MATCH(1,(MIN(IF(C7:C10-E6>0,C7:C10-E6,(C7:C10-E6)*-1))=IF(C7:C10-E6>0,C7:C10-E6,(C7:C10-E6)*-1))*1,0))}
```

I am keying off of the matching date so as to avoid making this formula super huge.

Equation itself is simple enough: 
We take a range and subtract each cell in that range by another cells value. If the output one of those calculations is negative we make it positive by multiplying by -1. We do this twice. With one of these arrays we apply the MIN function, leaving us with the smallest number in that array. We then compare each cell in the remaining array with this min value. The result is an array with same number items as the array we just used in the comparison, filled with trues and falses, that is equal to or not equal to our min. We then take array and multiply each item in it by 1, thereby converting the true/false values into binary 0 and 1s. We then match this array with 1. the first match, 1 with a 1 in the array, will get us our row.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both of these work, but if I change the 12/25/2016 date, I get a #Ref error, any thoughts on that?

Comment: @mcadamsjustin your question inspired me to take a look at all of error messages that excel functions return .... and many of them are not all that informative lol but here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-ref-error-822c8e46-e610-4d02-bf29-ec4b8c5ff4be

Comment: @Jeeped you offered no help and are just trying to demean me, why even post that?